# Progmatically setting a swagger-ui authorisation

Tags: javascript, swagger-ui

I have some swagger with a single security definition, which rightly creates an authorisation element in Swagger-UI 2.10.

```
"securityDefinitions": {
    "Api Auth": {
        "name": "Authorization",
        "in": "header",
        "type": "apiKey"
    }
}
```

I also have some custom JS, which gets a test bearer token and ensures that each request supplies this token.

```
var apiKeyAuth = new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken, "header");
window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("bearer", apiKeyAuth);
```

However, this seems to bypass the entire UI layer, so whilst my requests are authrised, swagger-ui does not show the client at being authorised.  Is there another path (short of virtual mouse-clicks) that I can take to authorise my client and keep the UI in sync?